# How to Upload Android APK to Fabric Beta

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric-beta

**What I want?**

I have an Android App that I want to upload to Fabric Beta.

**How do I want it ?**

I want to upload my Android App to Fabric Beta using Fastlane.

**What goes wrong ?**

After running my fastlane `fastlane beta` command, I get a nice report that everything is fine and I should see my app on Fabric dashboard:

> [16:06:57]: Uploading the build to Crashlytics Beta. Time for some ☕️.
>
> [[16:07:03]: Build successfully uploaded to Crashlytics Beta
>
> [[16:07:03]: Visit https://fabric.io/_/beta to add release notes and notify testers.

But when I go *https://fabric.io/_/beta*, my app DOES NOT appear there !

**What else did I try?**

Tried the [official integration doc](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install). Installed the Fabric plugin on Android Studio.Logged in with my credentials,selected my app bundle identifier and always get throwed to credentials screen from the *"All Kits"* screen.Looks like a bug to me.Didn't find solution for that anywhere.

**Did I try to integrate Fabrik SDK by hand and run the app ?**

Yes I did, and the app still didn't appear in the Fabric dashboard.Didn't see any related errors in the logcat.

**What about uploading using Gradle Plugin?**

That one was tricky because I had to fix numerous errors and provide fabric.properties file with my credentials, but eventually got a promising message :

> > Task :application:crashlyticsUploadDistributionGoogleProdStagingAlpha
> >     Uploading /Users/yanbraslavsky/booking-app/application/build/outputs/apk/googleProd/stagingAlpha/application-google-prod-stagingAlpha.apk to Crashlytics...
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s

And still no app in the Fabric dashboard.

**What do I want now?**

I have an Android App that I want to upload to Fabric Beta...

Comment: `Uploading the build to Crashlytics Beta.` Have you registered for beta access to Crashlytics Beta? (check: http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/)  Also, are you aware Fabric is getting deprecated soon? (check: https://get.fabric.io/roadmap) Its tools will be available in Firebase

Comment: Does adding --verbose to your fastlane command provide any other useful output? Did you ensure that your API key and API secret were correct? And have you made sure to follow all the installation instructions (https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) and build and run your app before attempting to upload a distribution?

Comment: @Zun Yes I am registered. In fact I have 5 other iOS projects I uploaded using fastlane. And yes I am aware it is being deprecated, but there is no alternative yet provided by Google so I decided to stick with Fabric.

Comment: @KevinKokomani I made sure my API key and secret are correct. Also run my app and followed installation instructions. The outcome is mentioned in my question. fastlane --verbose just gives me an extra info on how the upload is being done, no errors or warnings.

Comment: Strange - could you reach out to support(at)fabric(dot)io with a description of the steps taken, your app's package name, and a link to this post? Going through the support channel will allow a deeper dive into this.

Comment: @KevinKokomani Reaching support is a good idea,I've sent them an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric/Firebaser here -

This issue was solved over the Fabric support channel! When attempting to upload a Beta distribution to Fabric, first make sure that the app is onboarded properly (visible on your dashboard at fabric.io). If it isn't, the above can happen where you still get a successful upload result without being able to view the distribution.

If you've included all the Fabric dependencies and are still having trouble seeing the app on your dashboard, try running a clean of the project, then building, waiting some time, and running the app. If you still can't see the app after a few minutes, reach out to the Fabric support address with your package name/bundle ID.

Also make sure that your build.gradle is properly configured if you have multiple build configurations. In this particular app, the issue was in the applicationIdSuffix of one of the build configurations. Finally, check that you've used the correct API key and build secret from the Fabric organization settings - this ensures that you have permission to upload the Beta distribution and puts it in the right place.